# How to link choices in a model in Django

Tags: django-models, django-admin

Below I have the following model where I have two choices for country and timezone.  Note the time zone is complete the the code.

```
TZ= (
('gmt-10', 'Hawaii',
('gmt-8', 'Pacific',
...
)

class Agency(models.Model):
    agency = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=TZ)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=countries.COUNTRIES)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.agency
```

If user selects a country e.g. United States, in the admin site, how to I set up the the choices so the timezone is automatically filterd just to show the time zones for the US assuming I have a mapping table of time zones to countries as follows:

```
Mapping Table
usa gmt-10
usa gmt-8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [django smart selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects), it might be able to do what you want. If not you can always check out the source code for pointers.